# Regarding HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

whenever i am attaching a image in HTML5 the image size is getting so large.I gave the height and width also but it is not changing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Favourite movie</title>
    </head>
    <body> style="margin:0;<background-color:green:color:#ffff">
        <div style= "width:250px;">
        <h1>Favorite <Pic>></h1>
        <p> This is one of the favourite pics.</p>
        <img src="black cat.jpg" alt="My Favoutite Pic">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra ">" inside your body tag.

Comment: add width: 100% for img - `<img src="black cat.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="My Favoutite Pic">`

Comment: There is nothing preventing the image overflowing it's parent container is why

Answer (score 0):

You are missing height and width tags on the img tag. The size of the div wont affect it. It might help if you set it to something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Favourite movie</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0; background-color:green:color:#ffff">
        <div style= "width:250px;">
        <h1>Favorite <Pic></h1>
        <p> This is one of the favourite pics.</p>
        <img src="black cat.jpg" height="500" width="500" alt="My Favoutite Pic" >
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The width and height are just an example, pick the one that is right for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a redundant `<` in your `body` tag.
Then, you can use `width` and `height` attributes as below in the `img` tag to specify the image size

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Favourite movie</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0;<background-color:green:color:#ffff">
  <div style="width:250px;">
    <h1>Favorite
      <Pic>
    </h1>
    <p> This is one of the favourite pics.</p>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="My Favoutite Pic" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `height` and `width` image attributes, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Favourite movie</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;<background-color:green:color:#ffff">
        <div style= "width:250px;">
        <h1>Favorite Pic</h1>
        <p> This is one of the favourite pics.</p>
        <img src="black cat.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="My Favoutite Pic">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure to maintain the ratio of the length and width of the image, to keep the image looking good.

Answer (score -1):

You had an extra ">" in your body tag. Your code should be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Favourite movie</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;<background-color:green:color:#ffff">
        <div style= "width:250px;">
        <h1>Favorite <Pic>></h1>
        <p> This is one of the favourite pics.</p>
        <img src="black cat.jpg" alt="My Favoutite Pic">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```